# pass data from java script to php file in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, codeigniter

I had developed a event management system using javascript php and mysql. It works perfectly in plain php but now I need to migrate it into codeigniter and need some advice on how to pass the data from js to php while in codeigniter.

My front end java script function is like this

```
// event creating
                dp.onTimeRangeSelected = function (args) {
                    var name = prompt("New event name:", "Event");
                    dp.clearSelection();
                    if (!name) return;
                    var e = new DayPilot.Event({
                        start: args.start,
                        end: args.end,
                        id: DayPilot.guid(),
                        resource: args.resource, //Change to classroom name
                        text: name //Change to event name
                    });
                    dp.events.add(e);

                    args.text = name;

                    DayPilot.request(
                        "backend_create.php", 
                        function(req) { // success
                            var response = eval("(" + req.responseText + ")");
                            if (response && response.result) {
                                dp.message("Created: " + response.message);
                            }
                        },
                        args,
                        function(req) {  // error
                            dp.message("Saving failed");
                        }
                    ); 
                };
```

The php file handling the create function is like this

```
<?php
require_once '_db.php';

$insert = "INSERT INTO events (name, start, end, resource) VALUES (:name, :start, :end, :resource)";

$stmt = $db->prepare($insert);

$stmt->bindParam(':start', $start);
$stmt->bindParam(':end', $end);
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':resource', $resource);

$received = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

$start = $received->start;
$end = $received->end;
$resource = $received->resource;
$name = $received->text;
$stmt->execute();

class Result {}

$response = new Result();
$response->result = 'OK';
$response->message = 'Created with id: '.$db->lastInsertId();

echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Now on migrating to codeignitor I moved to segregated the `backend_create.php` file into model and controller and it looks like this.

**The controller part**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class TimecalCon extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
         $this->load->model("Timecal_model");
    }
public function insert()
    {
        $received = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

        $start = $received->start;
        $end = $received->end;
        $resource = $received->resource;
        $name = $received->text;        
        $this->Timecal_model->InsertDetails($name, $start, $end, $resource);       

    }
```

**The Model**

```
<?php   if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');


class Timecal_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function InsertDetails($name, $start, $end, $resource)
    {

        $insert = "INSERT INTO events (name, start, end, resource) VALUES (:name, :start, :end, :resource) ";       
        $query = $db->prepare($insert);
        $stmt->bindParam(':start', $start);
        $stmt->bindParam(':end', $end);
        $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
        $stmt->bindParam(':resource', $resource);
        $stmt->execute();
        class Result {}
        $response = new Result();
        $response->result = 'OK';
        $response->message = 'Created with id: '.$db->lastInsertId();
        return json_encode($response);
    }
```

The issue is when I change the javascript in the view page and use it like this

```
.....
 DayPilot.request(
                        "TimecalCon/insert", .......
```

The functionality breaks and I am unable to insert events into the db. How should I be passing the data from js to the controller in this condition?

Comment: Try add the base_url before  "TimecalCon/insert". 
Like, '<?php echo base_url()."TimecalCon/insert";?>'

Comment: try with '<?php echo base_url()."index.php/TimecalCon/insert";?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can send the value from javascript to controller using Ajax. I have some code of mine which may help you.

```
 function deleteEmp(empid){

        var base_url = '<?php echo site_url(); ?>';
        var r=confirm("Do You Really Want to Delete? ")
        if (r==true)
        {
            objPost= new Object();
            objPost.empid   = empid;
            $.ajax({
                url:"employee_registration/deleteEmp?empid="+empid,
                type:"POST",
                data:objPost,
                beforeSend:function(data){
                },
                error:function(data){
                },
                success:function(data){
                    alert(data);
                    result=JSON.parse(data);
                    alert(result);
                    if(result.status == 'success'){
                        alert('Deleted Successfully ');
                        window.location.reload();
                        return false;

                    }

                }

            });
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

As you can see I have pass the empid from my view to controller using ajax which gives me result back in variable. Which in this case is json.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DayPilot.request("<?php echo base_url().'TimecalCon/insert';?>",...)
```

You'll have to add "url" in "autoload.php" under config folder, then check if the url being loaded is the right one if not. Try modifying base_url() a bit like adding or removing the "index.php" part in the url.

Hope This helps